# Sphinx extension adding table content not shown in List of Tables

Tags: python-sphinx

I have developed an extension to add (my special) table content to my Sphinx Document (see https://github.com/procitec/sphinxcontrib-rst-table)

I used the example from https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/development/tutorials/recipe.html. This works fine. The table and all content is shown properly

But: the extension adds all tables to its "custom" Index, but i want to add the generated tables to the normal "List of Tables" (where e.g. all ReST Tables are listed)

How can i have both?

My Custom Index Entry and also the "table" listed in the "List of Tables" of the document?

Below is the code to generate my custom index entries:

```
class TableIndex(Index):
"""A custom index that creates an table matrix."""

name = "tbl"
localname = "Table Index"
shortname = "Table"

def generate(self, docnames=None):
    content = defaultdict(list)

    # sort the list of tables in alphabetical order
    tables = self.domain.get_objects()
    tables = sorted(tables, key=lambda table: table[0])

    # generate the expected output, shown below, from the above using the
    # first letter of the recipe as a key to group thing
    #
    # name, subtype, docname, anchor, extra, qualifier, description
    for _name, dispname, typ, docname, anchor, _priority in tables:
        content[dispname[0].lower()].append((dispname, 0, docname, anchor, docname, "", typ))

    # convert the dict to the sorted list of tuples expected
    content = sorted(content.items())

    return content, True
```

The table itself is added in class

```
class TableDirective(ObjectDescription):
```

in the run Method as

```
node_table = nodes.table(classes=classes, ids=ids)
```

Comment: Ok, the problem is related to a missing title (caption) of the table. If the title is visible, the table appears in the List of Tables

Answer (score 0):

After adding a caption (title) to the table it worked as expected.
The caption was given in the directive, but not properly parsed in the extension.